# NullPointerException in RxJava hot observable stream

Tags: rx-java

I have a stream where I'm observing the user's selected business. It should emit `null` when no business is selected. This is a hot observable so it should never terminate.

```
    @Override
    public Observable<Business> observeSelected() {
        return selectedDb.observe()
                .flatMap(businessId -> observe(businessId);
    }
```

There are two important method calls here

1. `Observable<String> selectedDb.observe()`

returns the `String businessId` of the selected business, or `null` if no business is selected.

2. `Observable<Business> observe(String businessId)` 
   returns the `Business` with #1's `businessId` , or `null` if no business with the specified ID is found

If #1 or #2 emit `null`, I want the entire method to emit `null` once.

Obviously, this code will throw `NullPointerException` when #1 or #2 emit nulls. I could litter the above code with null checks and emit null, but it would make it very ugly. Is there a way to catch only NullPointer exceptions with RxJava? I could use `.filter()` to prevent nulls from being emitted, but I still want to emit an `onNext(null)` when no business is selected.

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

A ternary expression seems to be the best bet, although still a little ugly.

```
@Override
public Observable<Business> observeSelected() {
    return selectedDb.observe()
            .flatMap(businessId -> businessId != null ? observe(businessId) : Observable.just(null));
}
```